# how to create a cell view which has a button and a "shorter cell" like contacts app?

Tags: iphone

I haved tried to create a view with a UIButton and a tableView Cell,
then I set the header view to be this view.
However,the cell in the header is not rounded-rect, besides,how to handle the cell's event,when user click this cell.

I haved tried to use custom cell also, but how to create a button and a shorter cell in a row?
when you select the cell,will not affect the button state?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can fake this in a number of ways. The simplest is to layout a rounded rectangle UIButton in your header, and turn off userInteraction for it so that it's just decorative.

Comment: Do you mean that I layout two UIButtons in tableView's header?
and fake one of it as a cell?

Comment: thanks,but it seems a little difficult.I want the cell to have a accessory disclosure button. when touch the cell,it is only highlighted,only when touch the disclosure button can trigger the action.

Comment: With this method, you probably can't use a built-in accessory view; you'll have to add your own, manually.

Comment: Add my own? Do you mean adding my accessory view to the button?But how to determine whether the user touch the accessory view or not?

Comment: ok,I got it.I use two buttons,one button(Round Rect) as the cell,then add another button to it and set its type as detail disclosure.
thanks a lot for enlighten me